# Album artwork missing after iTunes -> Music conversion

Tags: itunes, music, music.app, album-art

After changing my iTunes Library from iTunes to the new Music app on Big Sur many of my music files are missing album artwork inside the new Music app:

[image: Music App missing covers]

The thing that's worth nothing is that album artwork was embedded inside the .m4a files. There's a thumbnail of the image near the controls on music app, but it does not show as a big image on the application itself.

If I fire up the "mini player", the cover appears on top but not on individual files:

[image: Miniplayer]

Finally if we get to the filesystem itself, Finder is able to load and show the covers in individual files, observe the icons near the filename.

[image: Files in Finder]

If we look at additional information from Finder shows the artwork correctly too, and as you can see I've the file since 2011:

[image: More info on Finder]

Last but not least, there's the "more info" directly on the Music.app missing the cover:

[image: Missing cover in more info Music.app]

I even checked the tags on other software, in my case I just used [Foobar2000](https://foobar2000.org) to check for metadata and foobar2000 detected everything as it should:

[image: foobar2000 Details]
[image: foobar2000 Artwork]

So at the end my years-organized collection just lost almost 50% of the covers and is looking like some unorganized iTunes installation from the no tag MP3 era, the 90's:

[image: Sad music collection]

Any ideia of what may have happened and any idea on how to automate and fix this?

Thanks.

PS: I'm aware of the amusing dougscripts.com but now it's payware and I'm not sure if the scripts would solve the issue or not, it seems that even with the scripts it's a lot of manual work to fix my entire collection because something broke with Music.app.

**EDIT:** I've observed that all missing covers are embedded on PNG format. Those showing up are all JPEG.